# Reducing java security settings

Tags: java, linux, security, applet

I have an applet I am trying to run from localhost. However, I just updated the java client and now java blocks the applet from running because it is self-signed. This is apparently a new security update to Java 7 Update 51. I have found the [following article](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml) talking about how to reduce security levels. However, the article only mentions how to change security levels in Windows/OS X. Does anyone know how I can change the security levels in Linux so that I can run my applet on my linux box?

Comment: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/enable_console_linux.xml

Comment: perfect. If you want to add that as an answer I will accept it for you.

Comment: This should be what you are after http://www.java.com/en/download/help/enable_console_linux.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you follow all of the above and it doesn't work, for me, the Java console hasn't worked for years, and I have no memory of how to make it work.

I still have PCRAnywhere, an old, Java-based remote radio server application running on Debian Bullseye on a Pi.

My work-a-day laptop runs Neptune Linux.  This is what has finally worked for me. YMMV.

My solution is this (3 May 2023), I finally found the file. NO answer anywhere on the internet was found over years on and off of searching:

```
cd /home/~/.java/deployment/security
nano exception.sites
```

Add the server IP address e.g. Ensure you do not miss the trailing slash.

**`http://192.168.57.234:18080/`**

`ctrl-o` to save

`crtl-x` to exit

That's it.

You will be hit with Java security warnings, but I've got my setup behind a firewalls and VLAN's in place, so I think I've done enough.

I hope that helps someone; it's had me baffled for YEARS!